# How to solve the equivalent circuit of the induction motor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, power-electronics, induction-motor

Let's say I have below given equivalent circuit of the induction motor.

[image]

The parameters \$R_S\$, \$R_{Fe}\$, \$R_{load}\$, \$X_M=2\pi\cdot f\cdot L_M\$ and \$X_L=2\pi\cdot f\cdot L_L\$ are known and the \$\hat{V}_S\$ is also given. The goal is to calculate the \$\hat{I}_S\$, \$\hat{I}_{Fe}\$, \$\hat{I}_M\$, \$\hat{I}_0\$ and \$\hat{I}_R\$.

I have chosen the nodal voltage method for the two unknown nodal voltages \$\hat{V}_M\$ and \$\hat{V}_R\$ for calculation of the unknown currents. I have applied the Kirchhoff current law for the nodes. So I have following equations for the \$\hat{V}_M\$ node:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
-\hat{I}_S + \hat{I}_{Fe} + \hat{I}_M + \hat{I}_R &=& 0 \\
-\frac{\hat{V}_S - \hat{V}_M}{R_S} + \frac{\hat{V}_M}{R_{Fe}} + \frac{\hat{V}_M}{i\cdot X_M} + \frac{\hat{V}_M - \hat{V}_R}{i\cdot X_L} &=& 0 \\
 \left(\frac{1}{R_S} + \frac{1}{R_{Fe}} + \frac{1}{i\cdot X_M} + \frac{1}{i\cdot X_L}\right)\cdot \hat{V}_M - \frac{1}{i\cdot X_L}\cdot \hat{V}_R &=& \frac{\hat{V}_S}{R_S}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

and below given equation for the \$\hat{V}_R\$ node
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
-\frac{\hat{V}_M - \hat{V}_R}{i\cdot X_L} + \frac{\hat{V}_R}{R_{load}} &=& 0 \\
-\frac{1}{i\cdot X_L}\cdot \hat{V}_M + \left(\frac{1}{i\cdot X_L} + \frac{1}{R_{load}}\right)\cdot \hat{V}_R &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

i.e. in matrix form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{R_S} + \frac{1}{R_{Fe}} + \frac{1}{i\cdot X_M} + \frac{1}{i\cdot X_L} & -\frac{1}{i\cdot X_L} \\
-\frac{1}{i\cdot X_L} & \frac{1}{i\cdot X_L} + \frac{1}{R_{load}}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{V}_M \\
\hat{V}_R
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\hat{V}_S}{R_S} \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am not sure whether I have formed the equations for the unknown nodal voltages correctly. May I ask you for your opinion? Thanks in advance for any remarks.